# Tkinter python GUI trouble with module and __init__

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scipy

so I found this program, "BoxParti" made by user tpvasconcelos and I think it could help me greatly with research. Sadly it uses some packages I have never used before and it's kinda problematic to get it to work for me. I didn't change anything in the code but it doesn't want to work with me. Problem is mainly with tkinter and i'm not really familiar with it. I never used GUI before so it's kinda all tricky to me. At the moment I only want to make the program work and check if it could really be useful for me. I've been trying to make it work by myself but I didn't suceed sadly. It's kinda complex for me since I haven't used python in a while + haven't really ever used GUI with anything. Below I paste the link to download the code. I run it on Python 3.8 or 2.7, on both versions i get same errors. Below the link I paste error logs. I would greatly appreciate any tip that could sort of push me in the right direction because it seems to me I'm very lost

https://github.com/TPVasconcelos/BoxParti

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BoxParti.py", line 1493, in <module>
    app = BoxParti()
  File "BoxParti.py", line 53, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "BoxParti.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.make_plot(frame)
  File "BoxParti.py", line 176, in make_plot
    self.canvas.show()
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Comment: maybe it is an older version of tkinter that was used for the library because otherwise this is pretty unfixable as it seems (maybe can change source code), also when testing with python 2.7 did You use `Tkinter` or `tkinter`?

Comment: I used Tkinter if i remember correctly, otherwise it wasn't importing the package the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may work in early versions of Python, e.g. python 3.5. Several things have been deprecated. That means, you have to find correct packages.

For instance, if you uncomment the following the code runs on Python 3.8.

Uncomment: `#self.canvas.show()` in lines; `177, 610, 646, 692, 817, 1268, 1299, 1371`

also uncomment; `self.canvas.get_tk_widget()#.grid(row=0, column=1)`, in lines `179, 819.`

But it does not show 2D or 3D anime. This could be because of uncommenting `self.canvas.show()`.

**As a result, if you want to run this code, you have to find older versions required libraries. Which I do not suggest.**

***Instead of that, BoxParti have been expanded to [mdsea](https://github.com/TPVasconcelos/mdsea), you can install mdsea which may work better.***

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a ton, I didn't see this mdsea program before. It's much more complex I think but maybe I will be able to make it useful for me. Also thanks for noticing that I can run the program by uncommenting some lines, didn't notice it before. Sorry for any trouble :)